# rqt_graph rqt_tf_tree issue | ros indigo

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am facing an issue with the packages rqt_graph and rqt_tf_tree. When I run the mentioned packages I get the following error:

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 202, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 226, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 259, in _update_graph_view
    self._redraw_graph_view()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 292, in _redraw_graph_view
    same_label_siblings=True)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 254, in dotcode_to_qt_items
    graph.nodes_iter = graph.get_node_list
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_node_list'
```

Any clue on how can I fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239274/rqt_graph-rqt_tf_tree-issue-%7C-ros-indigo/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-12**:
Does this persist if you remove `.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini` (make a backup first)? It might be in a slightly different location, depending on your desktop environment.

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-07-12**:
Yes, the problem persists after the remotion of the mentioned file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-12**:
Must say I have no idea, have not run into this myself. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857448) seems similar. Do you have any name in your ROS tf tree that contains a character that pyDot might not like?

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-07-12**:
No. I am just running **roscore** and the command **rqt_graph**.

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2016-08-01**:
Got the same problem, ROS indigo on OSX. Originally I had the error `NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined` , then I updated pydot and pyparsing from 1.0.2->1.2.2 and 2.1.4->2.1.5 and got your error.

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-08-01**:
The packages are updated!!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found some versions that seems to work (ROS indigo, /rosversion: 1.11.20, OSX).

I downgraded pydot to version 1.0.29: `pip install pydot==1.0.29`, and now rqt_graph seems to work fine.

---

Originally posted by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) with karma: 61 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-13**:
Could you report this at [ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues)? Thanks.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-08-17**:
It was reported in https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/393 and has already been fixed.

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2016-08-17**:
Yes, I reported it on github. Sorry for not linking that here.

**Comment by [dexter05](https://answers.ros.org/users/27787/dexter05/) on 2016-08-24**:
Thanks! Downgrading pip worked for me. Was facing the same issue with ROS Indigo on Mac OS X El Capitan

**Comment by [Petro_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/28104/petro_19/) on 2016-09-28**:
Downgrading works for Jade too. Thanks!